# Quebrar celulas/td da tabela no html

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho uma página gerada dinamicamente com `php`/`sql`, nela existe uma `tabela` com dados dinâmicos, a `tabela` está dentro de um `div` que limita e organiza as extremidades e tamanho da página. Mas ela não esta sendo exibida como deveria, quebrando os `td` para uma nova linha abaixo e não lado a lado como mostra num exemplo grosseiro abaixo, esgotei minhas tentativas, não sei como proceder adiante, por isso peço orientação de como organiza-lá.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!--CDN-->
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Bootstrap-editable-->
 <link href="bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>

<!--Bootstrap3-Dialog-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap3-dialog/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
 <script src="assets/bootstrap3-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

<!--momentjs plugin for datetime etc-->
        <script src="http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/momentjs/moment.min.js"></script> 


<!-- Fix Bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/stylebox.css">
<!--<script src="assets/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> -->

<!--Bootstrap-->

<!--<link href="assets/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

<!--<script src="assets/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

<!--Bootstrap jQuery Validation Plugin-->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
div.image {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 80px; 
    width: 80px;
    padding: 3px;
 float: left; 
 margin-bottom: 1px;
    background: whitesmoke; 
 /*border-bottom: 2px groove rgb(27, 18, 236);*/
}

.header {
display: table-caption;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.header:hover {
background-color: rgb(221, 221, 238);
border-radius: 3px;
}

a:hover.header{
text-decoration: none;
}

a.header {
font-weight: bold;
//color: grey;
color: rgb(68, 67, 67);
}

a.header  {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
 -moz-filter: grayscale(50%);
 filter: grayscale(50%);
 width: 90;
}

a.header:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
 -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
 filter: grayscale(0%);
}

tr {
 vertical-align: top;
}

span.stxt {
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px !important;
}

p.boxtable { os p -->
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

p.boxtable
{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;    
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;   
}

</style>
</head>

<div id="content">
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="entry-boxeditable" id="boxedit-0">
<p class="boxtable" style="background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.25);">
  

<table id="1" "><tbody><tr><th>Grupo 1 even</th></tr><tr>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=6"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">outronome</span></a></td></tr></tbody></table></p><p class="boxtable" style="background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.25);"><table id="2" class="table "><tbody><tr><th>Grupo 2 odd</th></tr><tr>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=404"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">Select another</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td></tr><tr>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=0"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">test</span></a></td></tr></tbody></table></p><p class="boxtable" style="background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.25);"><table id="3"><tbody><tr><th>Grupo test even</th></tr><tr>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=1"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">Sample Codes</span></a></td>
<td><a class="header" href="url.php?p=4"><div style="content:url(); border: 2px solid red;" class="image"></div><span class="stxt">Normal #1</span></a></td></tr></tbody></table>
</p></div>
  
</div></div>
```

Comment: Acho que devias resolver isso com divs e não com tabelas e tentar partir linhas ao meio. Se colocares o código que gera esse HTML podemos ajudar a transformar isso.

Comment: Então Sergio, depois de muito pesquisar achei uma possível solução, amanhã vou atualizar o código e ver no que dá. Realmente as tabelas estão bagunçando tudo, até porque quando a página for redimensionada o problema iria continuar.

Comment: @Sergio Embora concorde, eu próprio recentemente me vi com um problema parecido: tenho uma tabela, tabela mesmo (i.e. dados dispostos de forma tabular), e preciso que ela fique boa em resoluções bastantes diferentes. Quase perguntei aqui, aliás, mas no final acabei buscando por *"responsive table"* e achei [várias soluções](http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns), só me falta analisá-las e escolher uma...

Comment: @mgibsonbr interessante. Vou ficar de olho aqui para ver um exemplo.

Comment: Concordo com o @Sergio, esse problema o correto seria resolver com divs, além de mais fácil, deixa mais elegante o código.

Comment: @mgibsonbr a imagem que você colocou antes não abre para mim, dá uma olhada aqui https://jsfiddle.net/waow8am1/  roda e veja se é isso.

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan Desculpe, não entendi. Você comentou na pergunta certa e/ou pra pessoa certa?

Answer (score 1):

Com tabelas não conseguirá o esperado, deverá utilizar-se das divs e tentar com float:left e tamanho fixo "simular" uma tabela até com clear:both para fazer seu código.
Uma outra alternativa para torná-lo "semi-responsivo" apesar de nao ser o que espera, é voce setar porcentagem ao width de suas tds, dessa forma, ficarão proporcionais ao tamanho da tabela q ficará com width=100%.

assim ficaria:  e sua td: 
 Ou de acordo com sua necessidade. Por ex: 10 colunas vc pode setar 10% para cada ou 5% para 20 colunas. ou de acordo com a necessidade de tamanho de cada.

Espero ter ajudado.